# Google+ api moments insert unauthorized message

Tags: oauth, google-plus

I'm trying to insert moments, using access_token, that i generated here https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and receive "Unauthorized" message. What i do wrong?
My request is:

```
{
  "target": {
    "url": "http://example.com"
  },
  "type": "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
}
```

I send this data on
www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault?access_token=######, where ###### - my access token.

The response is:

```
{
  "error":{
  "errors":[
      {
        "domain":"global",
        "reason":"unauthorized",
        "message":"Unauthorized"
      }
    ],
    "code":401,
    "message":"Unauthorized"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, i solved it by adding "request_visible_actions" and also make sure you have the login scope set on your request i.e "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"